# Testing a JSF Application with JMeter

Tags: jmeter, jsf-1.2, viewexpiredexception

I am a trying to execute a test script for a JSF application.

I have followed the steps in from the below link:
[wiki.apache.org/myfaces/PerformanceTestingWithJMeter](http://wiki.apache.org/myfaces/PerformanceTestingWithJMeter)

My script is navigating through 5 pages. The issue is i am able load all the 4 pages without any issue, but i am getting view expired exception for one page.

Structure

Thread Group

```
    |- HTTP Cache Manager
    |- HTTP Cookie Manager
    |- HTTP Header Manager
    |- Once Only controller (Login)
            |- HTTP Request(Login page)
    |- Regular Expression Extractor (For the view ID)
    |- Recording Controller
            |- HTTP Request (Page 1.faces)
    |- Recording Controller
            |- HTTP Request (Page 2.faces)
    |- Recording Controller
            |- HTTP Request (Page 3.faces) -> Getting Error for this page and the response is blank.
            |- HTTP Request (Page 4.faces)
    |- Recording Controller
            |- HTTP Request (Page 5.faces)
```

Comment: Can you show your test plan structure and some responses you get ?

Comment: @PMDUBIK-INGENIERIE : Have added the test plan structure.

Comment: Can you indicate where you use the var from regexp

Comment: I am using the reg exp in all the faces files, where it is having a parameter javax.faces.ViewState and providing the parameter value as ${regexp-refname}